# auto select the option from the list of options without entering the value

Tags: linux, unix

The command is `"source meta-cmf-raspberrypi/setup-environment"`. After running this command it provides me with a list of environments, after which the user is supposed to give an integer value. Once the input is given the desired environment gets selected. I want to automate this command as the selected environment option remains same all the time.

**For example:** lets say when I run this command, I get a list as follows:

```
subhro@Subhro-ThinkCentre-M79:~/Desktop/rdkb_workspace$ source meta-cmf-raspberrypi/setup-environment
 1) meta-cmf-bsp-emulator/conf/machine/qemux86broadbanddev.conf
 2) meta-cmf-bsp-emulator/conf/machine/qemux86hybdev.conf
 3) meta-cmf-raspberrypi/conf/machine/raspberrypi3-64-rdk-broadband.conf
 4) meta-cmf-raspberrypi/conf/machine/raspberrypi-rdk-broadband.conf
 5) meta-cmf-raspberrypi/conf/machine/raspberrypi-rdk-broadband-musl.conf
 6) meta-cmf-raspberrypi/conf/machine/raspberrypi-rdk-hybrid.conf
 7) meta-cmf-raspberrypi/conf/machine/raspberrypi-rdk-hybrid-westeros.conf
 8) meta-cmf-raspberrypi/conf/machine/raspberrypi-rdk-mc.conf
 9) meta-cmf-raspberrypi/conf/machine/raspberrypi-rdk-mc-westeros.conf
10) meta-raspberrypi/conf/machine/raspberrypi0.conf
11) meta-raspberrypi/conf/machine/raspberrypi2.conf
12) meta-raspberrypi/conf/machine/raspberrypi3-64.conf
13) meta-raspberrypi/conf/machine/raspberrypi3.conf
14) meta-raspberrypi/conf/machine/raspberrypi.conf
15) meta-rdk-bsp-emulator/conf/machine/qemuarmbroadband.conf
16) meta-rdk-bsp-emulator/conf/machine/qemux86broadband.conf
17) meta-rdk-bsp-emulator/conf/machine/qemux86hyb.conf
18) meta-rdk-bsp-emulator/conf/machine/qemux86hyb-morty.conf
19) meta-rdk-bsp-emulator/conf/machine/qemux86mc.conf
20) meta-rdk-bsp-emulator/conf/machine/qemux86mc-morty.conf
21) openembedded-core/meta/conf/machine/qemuarm64.conf
22) openembedded-core/meta/conf/machine/qemuarm.conf
23) openembedded-core/meta/conf/machine/qemux86-64.conf
24) openembedded-core/meta/conf/machine/qemux86.conf
25) openembedded-core/meta-selftest/conf/machine/qemux86copy.conf
Please enter your choice of machine [1..25]:
```

I want to run a command such that it will select the option automatically. I have tried using `"echo"` and pipelining the command with the source meta-cmf command, it works. But I am looking for something else.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to set the `MACHINE` env variable to the machine you want to build for before calling the setup-environment script:

Example :

```
MACHINE="raspberrypi4-64" source meta-cmf-raspberrypi/setup-environment
```

Answer (score -1):

This also a method, that should work for this.
It select 9. option.

```
source meta-cmf-raspberrypi/setup-environment <<EOF
9
EOF
```